# Can we say "he picked his ear" to mean "to remove earwax from his ear canal" the same way we say "pick his nose/teeth"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We often say "he picked his teeth" meaning he removed food in his teeth, and "he picked his nose" meaning he removed boogers in his nose.

Is it common to say  "**he picked his ear**" to mean "to remove earwax in his ear"?

Comment: I don't think it's *common*, and it wouldn't automatically mean picking out earwax - it might mean picking at e.g. an earring. Depends how precise you want to be and what alternatives you have (you could say e.g. "stuck a fingernail in his ear" or "picked at earwax").